# How can I find the CS:EIP of a looping process in Windows?

Tags: c, windows, debugging, winapi

I have a large Windows program which is unexpectedly hard looping -- not running any message pumps.  I didn't write most of the program, although I did port it to Windows using the Win32 API.  The original program is written in C, with a little C++ in the Windows wrapper code I wrote as part of the port.

What I would like is something like Process Explorer which showed the EIP of a running process.  Or, some operating systems will let you break into a running process, and display the registers.

Comment: Try OllyDbg: http://www.ollydbg.de/

Comment: In other words, you need a debugger?  There's probably one that came with your compiler/IDE.

Comment: Right-click on the process in Task Manager and save a dump while it's hanging. You can then analyse that with WinDbg or Visual Studio.